# Increase session timeout in web application using Angular 8 and Rest API

Tags: angular, rest, http, post, timeout

In my web application developed in angular 8 and Rest API, I have a POST API call that takes a long time than usual (> 1 hour or more) in uploading and processing certain large documents in backend.

But I can see in my browser's network that after 4 minutes my request gets canceled automatically and in my backend below error comes:

Servlet.service() for servlet javax.ws.rs.core.Application threw exception: java.lang.IllegalSta teException

In angular I tried below code but it is not working out. I am using post api call:

````
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData, { params: payload }).pipe(
        timeout(36000000) // timeout I want to extend for 10 hours to read large files from backend.
      ).subscribe((response: boolean) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        if (response != null)
          this.fassungImportDataSource.next(true);
      });
  }```

Can anyone please help regarding this?
````

Comment: How should I increase my http post request timeout?

Comment: The timeout you're piping is the RxJS `timeout` operator. It would only listen to the observable in the frontend and emit an error it the obs didn't emit for the specified time. It doesn't have anything to do with the HTTP timeout. IMO the elegant way would be to make the upload multi-part and upload in chunks instead of one single upload.

Comment: There is no problem with file upload , after file gets uploaded in the backend, Backend reads/process the file which take much time request timeout occurs.

Comment: In that case you need to adjust the back-end to return the call once the upload is complete. You could check back after a while if the processing is complete. Or the better fit for this scenario would be to use WebSockets. It'd let you upload the file and get the processed answer back.

Comment: Ok, and Is there any way to increase observable emit timeout?